# Converting i1 type to integer value

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

For the following branch instruction

```
br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.end, !dbg !35
```

Since llvm is SSA, I can directly access the operand 0, to determine whether the comparison is true or not. The type evaluates to i1 but I am having trouble extracting the value (true or false)

```
BranchInst &I;
Value *val = I.getOperand(0);
```

Type yields to i1 type but when I tried to cast to

`ConstantInt *cint = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(val)` the casting does not seem to work? how do I go about it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question

```
 BranchInst &I;
    Module* module;
    IRBuilder<> irbuilder(&I);
    Value* value = irbuilder.CreateIntCast(I.getCondition(),
Type::getInt32Ty(module->getContext()), false);
```

This should convert i1 to i32.

Answer (score 1):

You want a different kind of cast — cast<> casts within your code, while what you want is a cast within the generated code, [CastInst](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CastInst.html). Boolean is a one-bit integer type, so what you want probably is a zero extension. `CastInst::Create(CastInst::ZExt, I.getOperand(0), …` should do.

Comment: I did not want to insert the instruction, just want to convert the value. I figured it out, I will post the answer